# Codemod - Reading a file in node that uses export syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, codemod

Working on an `npm` package that runs a codemod on any given source repository. As part of my codemod I am looking to replace certain values in the source repository. Before I replace those values I need to check for values in an object being exported from a specific file (let's call it `constants.js`) for those values to exist. The check above that I need to perform from `constants.js` is conditional. It is conditional to if the user of the codemod wants to look up the `constants.js` file. The `constants.js` file uses the `import..export` statement to export the object that I need.

Any pointers on how I can extract the object from that file? I can't really use the `babel` option here so I am trying to use the `fs` methods to get what I want. I used the `createReadStream` method to read the file, but parsing it to extract the default export seems very fragile. Is there a clean way I can get what I need?

In the example below, I want to be able to extract `Messages` so I can look up the `termsOfUse` for my codemod changes.

***Constants.js***

```js
const Messages = {
      termsOfUse: locale => (locale === 'en' ? `TERMS OF USE` : `CONDITIONS`),
};

export default Messages;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide more concrete details of what you want to build. If it is a codemod: code before -> code after. If you want to get values of Constants.js ESM import will be enough.